# Can I temporarily disable rendering of markers in Google Maps V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, performance

I have a map where at some point I draw around 14000 markers. If the bounds of the map is set to the entire area where the markers are drawn, it takes a long time to draw the markers (about 8 seconds). But if I zoom into an area where few/no markers will be drawn, then drawing the 14000 markers goes really fast, like 2-3 seconds.

I assume this is because the most time consuming process is to actually draw the marker icons to the tiles, and since the markers are added one at a time, the map is rendered a ton of times in a very short time span.

Therefore I wonder if it's possible to disable the map updating/rendering while I add my icons, then re-enable it when all the icons are added.

Any solutions with the similar effect is welcome

Comment: I can't see why adding 14000 markers to a map where they are all visible is even remotely useful. It's the number of markers you need to think about, surely, not how to speed up performance?

Comment: Implementing clustering and such is an issue for another time. For the time being, one line of code to disable the map rendering, then one line of code to re-enable it later would be a 400% speed increase

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Forgot to reference you in my above comment

Answer (score 2):

The rendering time goes down because api v3 doesn't add the 14 000 when you're zoomed in more tightly. It only adds the markers that are in the current bounds PLUS markers that are in the tile layer buffer around the edges (probably one or two tiles).

I'm kind of confused as to what you mean, but perhaps you want to add the markers only after the map has already been loaded:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'tilesloaded',addMarkersFunction);
```

All that being said, 14 000 markers is A LOT of markers. Clustering markers when you have this many is not even what I would consider optional any more.

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstood my intent. The reason it takes so long (as I explain in my question) is that the map **updates repeatedly** over and over **while** I'm adding my markers. The reason the time goes down when I zoom far in is that the map doesn't render/refresh so often, because most of the markers that are being added are, as you say, not in the bounds of the viewport, hence not forcing the tiles to refresh. I just need a way to stop the map from automatically refreshing the tiles continuously while I'm adding the markers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could create a lot of markers, not associate them with the map.  Then afterwards, call the setMap() function on each of them.

You could also only do this that fall within the current bounds.

And have you considered marker clustering to reduce the number of markers?

Would be useful to see your code.

Comment: Well, calling `setMap()` on them one by one is what I'm doing, and it's making the map start refreshing it's tiles after the first marker. I really just need a way to "switch off" the map automatically rendering while I'm calling `setMap()` on each marker, then get it to render just once when all the markers have been added instead

Comment: The only way to add markers to a map is during their INDIVIDUAL instantiation (using an object with the map property set to anything but NULL) or INDIVIDUALLY calling setMap() on each marker. There is no way to add all markers simultaneously. What you are saying doesn't make any sense. Tiles don't refresh when you add a marker to them.

Comment: @Adam: All I know is: When I **watch** the markers get added, it takes about 10 times longer than if I zoom in to an arbitrary location first. I must assume this is because they are being drawn in one by one as they are being added instead of being drawn all at once when they are all added.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [MarkerManager](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/tags/markermanager/) library in the [Google Maps API v3 Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/). It was designed for such problems. While there isn't much in the way of documentation, there are several useful examples and plenty of comments in the source code.

Comment: True - the answer you were looking for is "no". There are tricks to disable canvas markers (setting "draggable" to true), but with that many markers you're map will be almost unusable without canvas markers.